# Creating an NSXPCConnection from an XPC service

Tags: swift, xpc

I'm trying to create an application with an XPC service "A", which in turn tries to communicate with an XPC service "B". However, it is not working.

If I copy both XPC services to `Contents/XPCServices` in the main app, the `invalidationHandler` of the `NSXPCConnection` in A is called immediately and B does not appear to start at all.

If I copy the nested XPC service to `Contents/XPCServices/A.xpc/Contents/XPCServices`, then it starts B, but it immediately crashes with:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: App.app/Contents/XPCServices/A.xpc/Contents/XPCServices/B.xpc/Contents/MacOS/B
  Reason: image not found
```

`libswiftCore.dylib` exists in the `Contents/Frameworks` folder of the app, A and B.

(The other suggestions I found for the `Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib` error did not help: changing code signing identities, setting `Runpath Search Paths`.)

What am I doing wrong?

I know I can initialize the connection to B from the main app, and then pass it as an `anonymousListener` to A, but this sounds ugly.

Answer (score 2):

It works now after adding `@loader_path/../../../../Frameworks` to the `Runpath Search Paths` of B.